# How to show the given function g is continuous everywhere?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

How to show that $g(x,y)=\frac{(1-cos(x+y))}{(x+y)^2}$ when $(x,y)\ne(0,0)$ and $g(x,y)=\frac{1}{2}$ when $(x,y)=(0,0)$ is continuous everywhere in $\mathbb R^2$

Comment: How is your function defined on (1,-1)?

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define $g(x,y)$ to be $\frac 1 2$ whenever $x+y=0$. Only then you can say that the function is defined and continuous everywhere. To prove continuity note that continuity at $(x,y)$ is obvious if $x+y \neq 0$. So consider a  point of the type $(a,b)$ with $a+b=0$. Let $(t_n,s_n) \to (a,b)$. To show that $\frac {1-\cos(t_n+s_n)} {(t_n+s_n)^{2}} \to g(a,b)(=\frac 1 2)$ all you need is the following fact: $\\lim_{\theta \to 0} \frac {1-\cos \,\theta} {\theta^{2}} =\frac 1 2$. [ You can prove this last fact either using the series expansion of cosine function or using L'Hopital's Rule].

Answer (score 0):

If you define $g(x,y)=0$ along the line $x=-y$, then indeed $g(x,y)$ is continuous
everywhere. To prove this, you have to

- Prove that $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}g(x,y)=1/2$.
- Prove that whenever $(x_n,y_n)$ converges to some point along the line $y=-x$, then $g(x,y)$ tends to zero.
- Argue that for all other cases continuity is obvious.

Comment: What about $(1,-1)$?